# Am planning a migration from tenant to tenant

Tags: onedrive-for-business, spo

I would like some tips for tools to migrate SPO and one drive from one tenant to a new tenant will the Microsoft free tool work for SMT work for this kind of migration ?

Comment: Try to use Sharegate migration tool. It comes with 14 days trial version

Answer (score 0):

**Sharegate:** Sharegate is support O365 tenant to tenant migration. It is ease to use and Sharegate is available in UI and Powershell also.

**SMT:** Currently SPO to SPO migration is not supported.

**Note:** 14 days trial only available in Sharegate